# "here to 6" or "here until 6"?

Tags: word-usage

> I'm here to 6.

I am currently debating this sentence with a colleague. I say this should read "until 6", not "to 6". He insists he is correct.  Which way is right?

Comment: _Until_ is clearer; _to_ is colloquial in context.  Perhaps he is being too colloquial with you, given the nature of your relationship. That's what speech registers like 'colloquial' are really about -- who's allowed to talk to whom in what register.

Comment: *Here till 6* is another option, and in some situations *before 6*, *prior to 6*, or *towards 6*.

Comment: Maybe there are some native speakers who really do use ***to*** in this context, but it sound to me like something non-native speakers would say after repeatedly mishearing ***'til*** (understandable, since it's never stressed, and very often wouldn't be clearly enunciated).

Comment: Dialectal versions of *to* such as *[tae](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/tae_prep_adv_conj)* (Scots) can be used to mean until. So I wouldn't be surprised if *to* can be used similarly at least in some dialects.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, "to" is understandable but not idiomatic, and suggests (to my mind at least) that English is not the speaker's native language.

"Till" or "until" are both correct and idiomatic, and may refer to a duration or a condition. Take this sentence: "I won't speak to her to she apologizes," and you'll see the point.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds weird, but your colleague is actually giving you the pertinent parts of the statement:

"I'm here, (from 10 *or, whatever,)* to 6".

I like the sound of *until* or *'til* better, too; your associate is telling you his schedule, rather than his plans.

Comment: For the record, it's 'till' not 'apostrophe-til'. Just thought you should know...

Comment: Don't be a word fascist, Glasseyed.  Old people like me still use 'til quite often.  "Till" may be preferred, but the other is not yet recognized as a glaring beacon of ignorance.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's word fascism, especially on an English language forum, to correct a very common misconception: 'till' is its own word, not an abbreviation of 'until.' :-)

Comment: And if I'm not mistaken, till is etymologically older than until.

Comment: @Glasseyed I suppose one question is if the existence of *till* actually makes *'til* as an abbreviation of *until* invalid. It does seem a bit like a case of *till* having been mostly lost (regionally?) and then inventing something to explain the established phrases using it, though.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think it's simply a case of mistaken identity: assuming that 'till' is the short form of 'until.' I was under a similar impression till (hoho) I read H.W. Fowler. (q.v., if you haven't already: he's timeless. Also witty.)

Answer (score 0):

Both are fine...they just mean something slightly different.  *"To 6"* is giving a single time instant as an end time marker.  *"Until 6"* is specifying a time range, from now till the time you leave..which is 6.